# Removing meta information from posts on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove the post author and date on Wordpress posts. However, I'm not sure how to hide this information. I have tried the following. **Appearance -> Customize -> Theme Options -> Single Post Settings** and then adding the following snippet of code `.single-post-meta{ display:none;}` inside both **Ad Code - Below Post Title** and **Ad Code - Below Post Content**. However, this does not work. How to fix?

Comment: Maybe you should increase this property priority? What about `!important` ?

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: it depends on the theme you are using. Most of the current themes have option to disable it. If does not, you need to us css code with the specifc the Classes used in the container to print the Post metas.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good work around.

**Appearances-> Editor -> Style.css**

Style.css can fix most display problems. Specifically for my problem, I scrolled down to where it said `.post-info {...}` and changed the display tag from `display: block` to `diplay: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that CSS code in Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS instead.

Comment: In the additional CSS section, there is no place for code. Just a bar that says "image width" and "preprocessor."

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your WordPress theme. There might not be a way to make this change without editing the theme files.